What does "— ... —" mean here?
Webs of Humankind says

By 2010, the world had twice as many democracies as authoritarian regimes
—a remarkable turnaround since 1974. Durable dictatorships, such as those of Fidel Castro in Cuba, Hosni Mubarak in Egypt, Robert Mugabe in Zimbabwe—or the Communist Party in China—now were the exception.

What does "— ... —" mean here?
Does it mean the same as

Durable dictatorships, such as those of Fidel Castro in Cuba, Hosni Mubarak in Egypt, Robert Mugabe in Zimbabwe, and the Communist Party in China, now were the exception.

Why does it use "or" instead of "and"?

I suggest making the question title more meaningful, it looks like you're asking for the meaning of three dots (...) which you often  find in literature and messages, closed by dash marks. This type of punctuation is very unusual.

They are em dashes, used instead of parenthetical commas (to insert non-essential phrases)

apparently —...— is the morse code for the "equals" symbol

.... .- / .... .- / .-.. --- .-..

I think the first dash just marks a pause in the sentence; a semicolon could have been used instead, as I have done.
The other two dashes are used to separate the phrase or the Communist Party in China from the rest of the sentence. The first three countries mentioned were dictatorships led by one person. The author seems to have thought "I could include China in the list as well, although it is a dictatorship by a party and not a person," and used or because China is a slightly different case.

The em-dash  — is used to visually isolate a phrase or clause. The isolation corresponds with either a syntactic disjunction or with an exaggerated narrative pause not required by the syntax. The purpose of the isolation is to "shine a spotlight" on the isolated element.

The Khmer Rouge led an agrarian revolution in Cambodia in which nearly 2 million people — mostly the educated — were systematically executed as enemies of the people.
There was Papa Bear, Mama Bear, and Baby Bear — and, of course, Goldylocks.

